# Android facebook SDK 3.20 not show dialog for publish in sample and my app with id FB App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Not working sharing functional in my android app and sample facebook application.
In HelloFacebookSample, when I set App ID from new FB application sharing function not working (App not show request for publish permission). But when i use App ID from my old application it work correctly.
Also, login button work correctly with new and old App ID.
I think problem in configure in my new App in Facebook.

Comment: what is it that you are trying to do again?

Comment: I create another android application. I created first application 2 year ago. "developers.facebook.com" has been changed